# Can't load Pyrebase module in AWS Lambda

Tags: firebase, aws-lambda

I have a Python 3.6 lambda function in AWS.  I've packaged all the libraries from my requirements.txt file and deployed it.  When my function triggers, I get this error:

```
module initialization error: Cannot load native module 'Crypto.Hash._SHA256'
```

The only reference I can find is this [closed ticket](https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase/issues/157) in the package library.  But what is causing this issue?  How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This issue is likely related to your build environment. Many math heavy libraries in Python rely on natively compiled C modules for performance. You can read more about that [here](https://www.crumpington.com/blog/2014/10-19-high-performance-python-extensions-part-1.html)  If your build environment does not match the lambda's execution environment, python will not be able to load native modules compiled for your build environment. AWS Lambda's execution environment is based on amzn-ami-hvm-2016.03.3.x86_64-gp2 as documented [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/current-supported-versions.html).

I came across this same issue when using AWS CodeBuild to create a python deployment package using the aws/codebuild/python:3.5.2 build image. After using [this](https://hub.docker.com/r/awswift/amazonlinux/) as my build image, the lambda was able to load the native module. If you are building your deployment package locally, I would recommend you spin up a docker container with an image compatible with your lambda runtime and build on that container.